# Why edit that make easier to understand for new version of blender get rejected?

Tags: discussion

i would like to understand what make this edit not accepted by community ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/109170

In my opinion it help make thing more understandable as i personally copy the wrong version of the code before realise my mistake was just syntax of blender that changed over time.

[image: rejected]

Comment: Hi thanks for the edit. The answer already covered both versions, you just shuffled things around and switched the order. It doesn't seem to improve the answer content itself on any meaningful way or make it easier to read. Was there any particular reason or concrete goal for that edit?

Comment: See [When should I edit a question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Comment: I suppose the point here was "To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages" - in that the text of the answer was assuming '2.79' was the "current" version. Swapping it around makes the 'current' (2.8+) method the default with additional info for what it used to be. I suppose it's just a matter of opinion but if the majority of users need the 2.8 syntax then it's arguably better for the version from the edit. That said it would be a massive undertaking to go back and edit all posts to be more 2.8-centric. A compromise would be to add 'In blender 2.79 and below:' instead of edit.

Comment: Sometimes If I update a question with a longish script to 2.8, I use the revision link to point back to prior eg for this particular answer  [For 2,4 < version < 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/75525/2)